# base64 image from canvas to file upload HTML control

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

is it possible to have an image exported via canvas (`canvas.toDataURL("image/png")`) and bound to `<input type="file" />` upload control programmatically without the usage of server side technology (so, only javascript)?

So basically, my client has a `<form>` and among other fields he would like to have an editable image field which would be added to the file upload HTML control on POST. I can't do it any other way since the existing `<form>` is third party which means I can't modify the server side logic and the client insist on keeping that third party `<form>`.

So, I have a specific wish from a client and I rally don't know if this is possible.
Any tips/pointers/help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:
probably should have mentioned that the solution must work cross-browser up to an including IE7

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can achieve it using `FormData`. You need to covert the canvas image to binary using `BlobBuilder`. With `FormData` you can:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5),
    blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL),
    fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
fd.append("canvasImage", blob);
```

Here you can read more about this approach [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)